# HttpWebResponse resulted in Internal Server Error in threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I have built a program communicating with remote server. When I'm handling all messages (in JSON object) sequentially it's behaving correctly. However when I build it in threading it comes back with **The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.**

Would it be a problem in the configuration of the remote server? From the log I can see the requests would hit the remote server within 0.5s.

Below is the code how I communicate with the remote server.

```
void Execute(){

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(REMOTE_URL);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {                             
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }                        

    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = null;
    try
    {
        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();       
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        // Internal Server Error exception caught here.     
    }

    if (httpResponse != null)
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            // deserialize the result                                      
            streamReader.Close();
        }                
    }
    httpResponse.Close();

}
```

And here is how I start the thread.

```
ObjectManager o = new ObjectManager()
Thread thread = new Thread(() => o.Execute(parameter));
thread.Start();
```

I'm thinking it's either a problem in the threading or server configuration. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, there's nothing wrong with the threading.

The Error 500, indicates there's something wrong on the server.
There could be a number of possibilities, one being is the server (application) is unable to handle concurrent requests. 
Again you need to have a look at the errors on the server to get a better idea of what is going on at that end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it's rather a remote server I've no access to log. I could only do a work-around by catching the exception and repost.